# Vim set fileencoding

Tags: vim

I need to convert utf-8 between cp936 in vim, I would like to map F3 to do this job, What should I write in ./_vimrc

*like this:*

```
map <F3>
If fenc == uft-8
    set fenc = cp936
else fenc == cp936
    set fenc = utf-8
```

I really need your help!

Comment: No, you really need to learn how to use google.

Comment: A good question, would specify what you've learned through your own research, what you've already tried, and what part of that is giving you trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the line to ~/.vimrc :

```
map <F3> :if &fileencoding =~# 'utf-8'<CR>set fenc=cp936<CR>else<CR>set fenc=utf-8<CR>endif<CR><CR>
```